# Computing Bouligand derivative (B-derivative) of a min function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $H(x)=\min (f(x),h(x))$ where $f$ and $h$ are continuously differentiable functions from $\mathbf{R}^n$ to $\mathbf{R}^1$. Suppose that $f(z)=h(z)$ at some point $z \in \mathbf{R}^n$.

If we set $BH(z)v = \min (\nabla f(z)^Tv, \nabla h(z)^Tv)$ where $v \in \mathbf{R}^n$, then could we show that the following holds?

$$
\lim_{v \rightarrow 0} \frac{H(z+v) - H(z) - BH(z)v}{\|v\|} = 0
$$

In this case, $BH(z)$ is called a Bouligand derivative of $H$ at $z$ according to the paper that I'm reading.

In the paper, it says that the above limit trivially holds but I wasn't able to verify the claim. I really would like to learn how to show it. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows from the inequality 
$$|\min(a,b)-\min(c,d)|\le \max(|a-c| , |b-d|)\tag{1}$$
for real numbers $a,b,c,d$. The inequality is easy to check directly: let the right hand side be $m$; then $\min(c,d)\le \min(a+m,b+m)=\min(a,b)+m$ and similarly in the other direction.

Since $f(z)=h(z)$, it follows that $$H(z+v)-H(z) = \min(f(z+v)-f(z),h(z+v)-h(z))$$

Apply (1) with $a=f(z+v)-f(z)$, $b=h(z+v)-h(z)$, $c=\nabla f(z)^T v$, and $d=\nabla h(z)^T v$. Since $f$ and $h$ are differentiable at $z$, the right hand side is $o(\|v\|)$ as desired.